# What's the NSAttributedString conversion equivalent of the <pre> tag?

Tags: html, ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, pre

I am parsing HTML tags right now for rendering in a UITextView using NSAttributedStrings.

I'm a bit unsure as to how text encased in `<pre>` tags should render in a UITextView as an attributed string.

Should it just be formatted in the Courier font, or is there more to the `<pre>` tag?

Example:

```
This is text
that     is inside of
a pre tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the font should be `Courier` (or any other monospaced font that looks decent). You may also have to tweak certain whitespace characters, like tabs (i.e. convert them to spaces).

(Why not just use a `UIWebView`?)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I have used UIWebView, but I just want to be able to pull this off in a UITextView as well. I'm weird like that :)

Comment: Yeah, I can see the benefit of reinventing WebKit, which is the mostly widely-used HTML rendering engine in use today. ;)

Comment: I'll come back to this one day with a proper reason why.